# Destroy method does not clear the data

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

When I invoke `destroy()` and then create new chart object, `dygraph` plot old values and new values togheter. Seems like old dataset isn't be cleared properly.

I'm using `dygraph-combined.js v1.1.0`.

Here some code

```
function drawChart(){
    // Process data
    // Process labels

    if(!chart)
        dygraphFun();
    else{
        chart.destroy();
        dygraphFun();
    }
}

function dygraphFun(){
    chart = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("plot-div"), 
    mydata, 
    {
        labels: mylabels
    });
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code here?

Comment: I have edited with adding code

Comment: Are you sure you don't append new data in `mydata` variable?

Comment: Sure! _mydata_ and _mylabels_ are appended correctly.

Comment: Also, in console I found: GET http://myip/script/dygraph-combined.js.map **404 (Not Found)**

Comment: If they are `appended`, then they will appended in plot too. Can you show the code for the data creation? If you have a `404`, then you should check the file path :)